# Make A Different Popup Window For Each ID Inside A Table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need some help.

I used echo to display the ID but after I click each ID, the popup window appeared and will display the same page for all ID. I want to display a different page for each ID. How can I solve this? Thank you..

```
<td><a href="d1.php" onClick="javascript:void 
window.open('d1.php','1382580890418','width=800,height=600,toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1,s
tatus=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;"><?php echo $row["ID"]; 
?></a></td>

<td><?php echo $row["NO"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["CATEGORY"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["TYPE"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["BRAND"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["MODEL"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["SERIAL"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["YEAR"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["DUEDATE"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["REGION"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["STATUS"]; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with passing different name every row like :

```
 <td>
    <a href="d1.php" onClick="javascript:void window.open('d1.php','<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?','width=800,height=600,toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;"><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></a>
</td>
```

Different window name for every row by passing the row id as window names.
Ideally all rows should be handled by single window, by setting your logic at **d1.php**, but I still this can be a solution.